# How would you convert each int element of a 2D Array into a String?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a 10x10 `int[][]`, each element is a random `int`. For my specific purpose, I need to convert each `int` value into a `String` so I can use those values as an argument in `Label(text: String)`. I want to be able to traverse my array and do this conversion on each iteration. Obviously this is all I can muster up for this problem:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {


            }
        }
```

I tried using the `toString()` on each index, but NetBeans wasn't liking it, because I was obviously using it incorrectly. So if someone could give me some guidance on how this process works it would be greatly appreciated. And it may go without saying, but I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops seems to be alright. User `Integer.toString()` to convert an int to a String

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) 
{
    for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) 
    {
       String matrixElementStr = Integer.toString(matrix[row][column]); 

       // Call some method "Label(text: String)" with  "matrixElementStr" as a parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: So for every iteration is each index being tacked onto `elementStr` as one long `String`? Or is each index just becoming a `String` that `elementStr` can reference to?

Comment: each element (unique combination [row][column])in the matrix is converted to a string. which is what the OP asks for

Comment: I see. Then in the second iteration, this means `matrixElementStr` is referring to the current index which at the same time is converted to a `String`, yeah? Sorry for the drawn out questions, I just want to make sure I got a grip on what exactly is happening so I can understand.

Comment: best way to undertand this code is the outer loop runs once for each row. For each row the inner loop runs x times. where x is number of columns.